# How to create and display this vector ([0,5,5......,5,5]) with total length of a (an integer)

Tags: matlab, vector, repeat

While a solution would be nice I just need to know what i would use to create the vector (linspace, a:d:b) and how would I make it so that it has five after the first initial 0.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how you want to create such a vector using `linspace`, as this function creates a linearly spaced vector. And your entries, besides the first zeros, are all the same.

However, let us assume that the length of your target vector `v` is `n`

One possibility to create the vector `v` is the following way:

```
v=[0, 5*ones(1,n-1)];
```